# LDAP Strong(er) authentication required

Tags: php, ldap

I want to add the value to the attribute. This is my code below.

```
function set_attribute($attribute, $uid, $service)
{
    $entries = $this->get_account($uid);
    if ($entries != false && count($entries) == 1) {
        $entry = $entries[0];
        $result = $entry->add(array($attribute => $service));
        if (PEAR::isError($result))
            return false;
        else {
            $result = $entry->update();
            if (PEAR::isError($result))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

I failed to add new value to the attribute. This is the error when I dump this code `$result->getMessage()`

```
string(121) "Could not add new values to attribute serviceType: Strong(er) authentication required: LDAP_STRONG_AUTH_REQUIRED"
```

What's wrong with it. I find no solution at all even I have authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like `confidentiality required` error, when you need SSL/TLS enabled to secure the channel rather than a clear text connection.  Though you never know, since you do not clarify if your connection is secure or not.

I wonder if this is meant as a permission issue?  Or perhaps this is a case where, the system is allowing a clear text bind, but will not allow certain operations without secure comms on the connection.